# Logging and exporting conf to other modules

Tags: python, logging

Trying to level up my devOps skill I put log where I want/need to my code.
Catching an env variable I can setup if I want DEBUG/INFO log (dev) on the standard output or WARNING and above (prod) on a file.

But in python I didn't find how to set a logger conf once (in the main file ?) and use it to the whole project without having to re-write everything or transfer the logging object everywhere. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

EDIT : I made a log.py file that looks like this

```
import os
import logging
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from utils import get_timestamp


def get_logger():
    load_dotenv(".env")
    env_dev = os.getenv('ENV_DEV', "development")

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    log_format = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

    if env_dev == "prod":
        handler = logging.FileHandler(f'log/{get_timestamp("%Y%m%d")}_app.log')
        handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
        handler.setFormatter(log_format)
        logger.addHandler(handler)
    else:  # DEV
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        handler.setFormatter(log_format)
        logger.addHandler(handler)

    return logger
```

And I use it like :

```
from log.logging import get_logger
# On Dev env
logger = get_logger()
logger.info("Do stuff")
...
```

But I have no error nor log on my term.

Comment: Did you checked [logging's Basic Example](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules)?

Comment: You need to set the level on the logger itself too. It defaults to warning, and info is below warning. `logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)` before you return

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to transfer the logging object. When you configure or name a logger once it is globally available. So in your main file you would set up the logger and in all other places just use it.

**`main file`**

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('mylog')
if debug:
    mylog.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
mylog.addHandler(...)
# do all your setup

logger.log("log that") # use logger
```

**`other file`**

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('mylog')

logger.log("log this") # use logger, it is already configured
```

Comment: What I read id to use `logging.getLogger(__name__)` to have the current module. So I try to make a log module and import it everywhere i need. But now nothing is written on the terminal or the file is created but not log inside.

Comment: This is only needed if you want to have separate loggers for every module. It still works to configure just once. Just add all handlers to the root logger that you get by not using an argument. `root = logging.getLogger()`. all other loggers propagate to this logger, and you can can configure the level of the handlers there.

Comment: But do you mean that the configuration I made in `main.py` is still gonna be working on other file ? how come ?

Comment: It will work in every file that is used by main. `logging` creates a global reference to the loggers, so that the root logger is the same from every module.

Comment: I have edited my question with a sample of what I have just trying.